# SQL Pivot rows to columns without aggregate

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to figure out a straight value pivot.

I need to convert the rows into columns, the Employee have different question which is stored in rows,I want to show maximum of 3 questions against each employee
 Most of the examples I have seen have some from of aggregate included. I am looking to for a straight value pivot.
Source Table

```
EMPId   Question
 121    Should I refer for a desk assessment
 121    They have accused me of bullying
 121    what services can they be referred for ?
 121    what services can they be referred for ?
 122    They have accused me of bullying
 122    what services can they be referred for ?
 123    what services can they be referred for ?
```

Desired Output

```
+----------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  EMPId   |                Question1                 |                Question2                 |                Question3                 |
+----------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|      121 | Should I refer for a desk assessment     | They have accused me of bullying         | what services can they be referred for ? |
|      122 | They have accused me of bullying         | what services can they be referred for ? |                                          |
|      123 | what services can they be referred for ? |                                          |                                          |
+----------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Check here how format tables for SO. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/how-to-format-sql-tables-in-a-stack-overflow-post

Comment: Interesting... this question is tagged as SQL Server, though the question seems to be for HTML? If you really have a question a SQL Server, you would want to post some t-sql showing where you tried to get to, and then someone can guide you along.

Comment: @Eli The problem is OP doesnt know how to format the table in ascii format and use HTML, but SO doesnt format using html

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza agreed. Though I already looked past that issue, at what the OP is trying to accomplish, and it was upon that which I based my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking query like this below:

```
Select * from (
    Select *, RowN = Concat('Question', dense_rank() over(partition by EmpId order by Question) )
        from #questions
) a
pivot (max(Question) for RowN in ([Question1],[Question2],[Question3])) p
```

If your input is xml and if you are expecting translated xml this query will not work.

Output as below:

```
+-------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| Empid |                Question1                 |                Question2                 |                Question3                 |
+-------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|   121 | Should I refer for a desk assessment     | They have accused me of bullying         | what services can they be referred for ? |
|   122 | They have accused me of bullying         | what services can they be referred for ? | NULL                                     |
|   123 | what services can they be referred for ? | NULL                                     | NULL                                     |
+-------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You need to include only 3 question, but Is important OP explain what logic use to choose those 3.